# I have this problem when I try to do flutter pub get. How to solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I created a new flutter project where I put the flutter_bloc dependency but when I do flutter pub get I have this error.

[bloc] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in bloc...
Because bloc depends on flutter_bloc ^6.0.1 which depends on bloc ^6.0.0, bloc ^6.0.0 is required.

So, because bloc is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because bloc is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
can someone help me please?

[image: Mon fichier pubspec.yaml]

Answer (score 26):

I solved my problem because I created the project with the name block and it created conflicts with flutter_bloc. Thanks to those who bothered to read my question

Comment: the same here, lol, I just realized that I created the project with the name flutter_bloc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this bug by changing versions of a package which you need in the app. I have a problem with flutter_bloc: 7.0.1 and bloc: 7.0.1 versions and just add

```
flutter_bloc: any

bloc: any
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Error on line 33, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
   ╷
33 │   bloc: any
   │   ^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your application name from 'bloc' to 'anythingYouPrefer', the reason for your problem is contradiction with the package and your application name

Answer (score 0):

The error I got:

`Because flutter_bloc depends on flutter_bloc, version solving failed.`

The reason: Is the project name and library name is same.

(My) Solution: Create another project with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your **procject name** becasue there is a **conflict** with your project name like *bloc,flutter_bloc*.